# perl subroutine know if hash is passed or single values

Tags: perl, hash, arguments, subroutine

I'm writing a perl subroutine and I would like to have the flexibility to either pass in values as a hash, or just as single values. I would like to know how the arguments are passed to the subroutine, so that I can handle the cases separately. For example:

```
#case 1, pass in hash
test(arg1 => 'test', arg2 => 'test2');

#case 2, just pass in single values
test('test', 'test2');

sub test { 
    #if values passed in as a hash, handle one way
    if(...) { 

    }
    #if values passed in as single values, do something else
    else { 

    }
}
```

Is there a way to detect this in perl? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do using an anonymous HASH reference :

```
#case 1, pass in hash
test({arg1 => 'test', arg2 => 'test2'});

#case 2, just pass in single values
test('test', 'test2');

sub test { 
    my $arg = shift;

    if(ref $arg eq 'HASH') { 
        ...;
    }
    #if values passed in as single values, do something else
    else { 
         ...;
    }
}
```

See
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: That's a great solution! What's nice is I could also flip it around and have the hash reference around the single values if I want. Thanks!

Comment: not sure what you mean by "around the single values"?

Comment: I'd use `if (@_ == 1)` instead of `if (ref $arg eq 'HASH')`. It's usually buggy to check a value's type in Perl, and here is no exception.

Comment: @ikegami - actually I'd probably do both! arg2 might be optional, in which case `test('test')` would be a valid call. If you look at the constructors for Moose/Moo classes, they generally do something like `if (@_==1 and ref($_[0])=='HASH') { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: @tobyink, 1) That still suffers from the same problem. It just silences a warning. 2) `test('test')` is not valid for the OP, so it makes no sense to mention it. 3) If you do allow `test($string)` and `test($hashref)`, then you have really broken code cause it's impossible to tell the difference betwen the two (e.g. `test(URI->new('http://example.com/'))` is both).

Comment: @ysth I just mean lone values, values that are passed in not in a hash.

Comment: @srchulo, It won't work. They would have to be key-value pairs.

Comment: @ikegami why is that? If the first argument is a hashref, I would know to view the values inside the hashref individually and not to use them as a hash, whereas if the first value is not a hashref, I could interpret them as the key value pairs of a hash.

Comment: You can't wrap arbitrary scalars with curlies because you'll lose arguments if you have the same value twice at odd positions. Because you'll lose order, so you won't know which value was for which parameter. Because arguments at odd positions will be converted to strings. You can only use a hash ref if you have key-value pairs.

Comment: @srchulo: what you are saying is not making sense; can you show what you mean to do with single values in your code example?  you can't put single values in a hash.

Comment: @ysth You're correct. See ikegami's explanation above.

Comment: @ikegami, oops :) Thanks. You're right. I guess if I wanted to do it where the individual items were passed in in a reference, I would have to use an arrayref instead of a hashref, such as: `test(['test', 'test2'])`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Again, you shouldn't depend on value types. Just on the number of parameters. What you have there is ambiguous. Stick to `test($val1, $val2)` vs `test({ name1 => $val1, name2 => $val2 })` and `if (@_ == 1)`.

Comment: @ikegami, `test(URI->new('http://example.com/'))` is not a hash in any way, shape or form.

Comment: @tobyink, You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is perfectly fine (and I've plusplussed it), but in the spirit of There's More That One Way To Do It™, and in the interest of pimping my own wares...

```
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Kavorka qw( multi fun );

# define a function with positional arguments
multi fun test (Str $arg1, Str $arg2) {
   say "positional";
   say "\$arg1 is $arg1";
   say "\$arg2 is $arg2";
}

# define a function with named arguments
multi fun test (Str :$arg1, Str :$arg2) {
   say "named";
   say "\$arg1 is $arg1";
   say "\$arg2 is $arg2";
}

# Call the function with positional arguments
test('foo', 'bar');

# Call the function with named arguments
test(arg1 => 'foo', arg2 => 'bar');

# Call the function with named arguments again
test({ arg1 => 'foo', arg2 => 'bar' });
```